# How to properly replace toast message with alert Dialog?

Tags: java, android

I am new to Android development and am working on a audio stream app. I initially put a toast message to notify users when an error occurred while streaming audio service. However, I wanted to replace it with an alert dialog. But i have been getting an error.

Here is my previous code:

```
    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "There was an error playing the stream, Check your network connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            mediaPlayer.reset();
            return false;
        }
```

Here is my updated code which throws an error

```
public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View customTitleView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_theme, null);
        AlertDialog.Builder alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alertbox.setCancelable(true);
        alertbox.setView(customTitleView);
        alertbox.show();
        mediaPlayer.reset();
        return false;
    }
```

Here is the error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main                                                                        android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
                                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:589)
                                                                                          at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:326)
                                                                                          at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:224)
                                                                                          at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:149)
                                                                                          at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:277)
                                                                                          at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:932)
                                                                                          at com.musicianfocus.ben.wordedfm.RadioService.onError(RadioService.java:54)
                                                                                          at android.media.MediaPlayer$EventHandler.handleMessage(MediaPlayer.java:2001)
                                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
                                                                                          at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
        06-02 08:43:33.065 321-322/? E/SocketStream: readFully was waiting for 716352 bytes, got 16192 
        06-02 08:43:33.089 321-322/? E/SocketStream: readFully was waiting for 700160 bytes, got 16192 
        06-02 08:43:33.089 321-322/? E/SocketStream: readFully was waiting for 683968 bytes, got 16192 
        06-02 08:43:33.089 321-322/? E/SocketStream: readFully was waiting for 667776 bytes, got 16192 
        06-02 08:43:33.089 321-322/? E/SocketStream: readFully was waiting for 651584 bytes, got 16192 
        06-02 08:43:33.089 321-322/? E/SocketStream: readFully was waiting for 635392 bytes, got 16192 
        06-02 08:43:33.089 321-322/? E/SocketStream: readFully was waiting for 619200 bytes, got 16192 
        06-02 08:43:33.089 321-322/? E/SocketStream: readFully was waiting for 603008 bytes, got 16192 
        06-02 08:43:33.089 321-322/? E/SocketStream: readFully was waiting for 586816 bytes, got 16192 
        06-02 08:43:33.093 321-322/? E/SocketStream: readFully was waiting for 570624 bytes, got 16192 
        06-02 08:43:33.093 321-322/? E/SocketStream: readFully was waiting for 554432 bytes, got 16192 
        06-02 08:43:33.093 321-322/? E/SocketStream: readFully was waiting for 538240 bytes, got 16192 
        06-02 08:43:33.093 321-322/? E/SocketStream: readFully was waiting for 522048 bytes, got 16192 
        06-02 08:43:33.093 321-322/? E/SocketStream: readFully was waiting for 505856 bytes, got 16192 
        06-02 08:43:33.093 321-322/? E/SocketStream: readFully was waiting for 489664 bytes, got 16192 
        06-02 08:43:33.093 321-322/? E/SocketStream: readFully was waiting for 473472 bytes, got 16192 
        06-02 08:43:33.097 321-322/? E/SocketStream: readFully was waiting for 457280 bytes, got 16192 
        06-02 08:43:33.097 321-322/? E/SocketStream: readFully was waiting for 441088 bytes, got 161920 
        06-02 08:43:33.101 321-322/? E/SocketStream: readFully was waiting for 279168 bytes, got 155972 
        06-02 08:43:33.105 321-322/? E/SocketStream: readFully was waiting for 123196 bytes, got 16192 
        06-02 08:43:33.105 321-322/? E/SocketStream: readFully was waiting for 107004 bytes, got 16192 
        06-02 08:43:33.109 321-322/? E/SocketStream: readFully was waiting for 90812 bytes, got 16192 
        06-02 08:43:33.109 321-322/? E/SocketStream: readFully was waiting for 74620 bytes, got 16192 
        06-02 08:43:33.109 321-322/? E/SocketStream: readFully was waiting for 58428 bytes, got 16192 
        06-02 08:43:33.109 321-322/? E/SocketStream: readFully was waiting for 42236 bytes, got 16192 
        06-02 08:43:33.109 321-322/? E/SocketStream: readFully was waiting for 26044 bytes, got 16192 
        06-02 08:48:37.733 321-322/? E/SocketStream: readFully was waiting for 716352 bytes, got 16192 
        06-02 08:48:37.733 321-322/? E/SocketStream: readFully was waiting for 700160 bytes, got 16192 
        06-02 08:48:37.733 321-322/? E/SocketStream: readFully was waiting for 683968 bytes, got 1619
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: null pointer exception

Comment: post your stacktrace you are getting in case of null pointer exception

Comment: i have updated the question. pls review

Answer (score 0):

```
 AlertDialog.Builder builder;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context, android.R.style.Theme_Material_Dialog_Alert);
    } else {
        builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    }
    builder.setTitle("Connection Issue")
    .setMessage("There was an error playing the stream, Check your network connection")
    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
            // continue with on ok
        }
     })
    .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
            // do nothing
        }
     })
    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
    .show();
```